# How do I append D3 elements onto React components?

Tags: reactjs, svg, d3.js

I currently have a React page with multiple images that are based on an array of minutes that make up a total time period: [15, 10, 15, 5]. The images depict a bar graph, that shows the current period in light blue and the previous periods in dark blue:

[image: "bar graph"]

Currently the images are hard coded but I am trying to use D3 to dynamically generate them. I can do it in a unit using SVG but when I try to insert it into React it's giving me problems. Each image needs the overall minute array to show the correct information. I have the array in a props variable at the high level of the page component. I have tried to create a component based on the D3 component I programmed but I can't figure out how to append SVG elements in React. Before, I could append an "svg" onto "body" but I can't do that in React.

I've tried to follow this guide:
https://react-d3-library.github.io

I have my D3 component in a file called ChunkGraph.js.

But in that react-d3-library guide it imports node (a DOM element) from the D3 file, which gives me a compile error when I try it.

EDIT: Figured it out... for anyone who comes after and needs to know... useRef is the key here, to form a dynamic link between react and your d3 element. react-d3-library isn't needed.

[image: Like so]
[image: And here]

Comment: can you add what you have tried ?

Comment: Added an update. Thanks